# How to update google map without reloading in android?

Tags: android

In my project I have to track any vehicle through google map. In that case I have to update the marker position after 1 minute set by me . But my problem is that every time the google map get refreshed . Here is my code :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

String json_string;
JSONObject mJSONObject;
JSONArray mJSONArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();


    try {
        mJSONObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        mJSONArray = mJSONObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        String lat,lon,imei;

        for(int i=0;i<mJSONArray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject jo = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            imei = jo.optString("IMEI");
            lat = jo.optString("Lattitude");
            lon = jo.optString("Longitude");

            setUpMapIfNeeded(imei,lat,lon);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(String imei, String lat, String lon) {

        if (mMap != null) {
            double currentLatitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            double currentLongitude = Double.parseDouble(lon);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                    new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).zoom(18).build();
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(imei);
            mMap.addMarker(options);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
}
```

}

Please help me as I want not get the map reloaded every time the marker got updated .

Answer (score 1):

Using Events is perhaps the easiest way to do this sort of thing.

Basically, add a library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and every time you receive a new location data, inside your **onEvent()** method, update your marker position on the map.

The easiest way would be to clear the map first then add the marker like it is the first time. You could have a private method that you would pass the new Latitude and Longitude then let it update the map accordingly!

I hope this gives you an idea on how to solve your problem!

**EDIT**

I assume (loosely) that you use Gradle build system. Now, inside your build.gradle file: in your dependencies clause add this :

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, create a simple Java class like this:

```
public class VehicleLocationUpdatedEvent(){

    public void isLocationUpdated;

    public VehicleLocationUpdatedEvent(boolean updated){
        this.isLocationUpdated = updated;
    }
}
```

Next, in your Map activity or Fragment, you need to add the following pieces to listen for updates from other parts of the application - particularly when a new location data is received.

```
//inside onCreate .....
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

//inside onDestroy 
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);


//inside the activity, like any other method add this:
public void onEvent(VehicleLocationUpdatedEvent event){

    if(event.isLocationUpdated){

        //call your method that actually updates the marker position
        //this could simply be animating the camera to the new position
        //like I said, clear the map of the old marker if you want
    }
}
```

Now to actually use this event, you need to post it when you receive the new location data - like latitude and longitude. You can even modify the Event class to include latitude and longitude values so that you have them handy.

```
//to call the post method, simply do this
EventBus.getDefault().post(new VehicleLocationUpdatedEvent(true));
```

That is all you need to use events in Android! I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: Whoever downn-votes, please add a comment to give a reason

Comment: i dont know who give you downvote, but event based solution sounds like good and brillant. I think downvoter guy dont know about events ,i give you upvote. Maybe he just look answer's format dont read , just click downvote. Nowadays stackoverflow had users like that :(

Comment: i edited your answer: when instant run is enabled ,sometimes eventbus is not registering . Basically you can check register state before every post process.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to specify the icon for:

```
  MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(R.drawable.pin_stop)
                .title(imei);
        mMap.addMarker(options);
```